# Php / Jquery - Click & display MySQL data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, parent

Basically I'm just asking about the best approach for my idea. So, what I have right now is a class that stores all my table information from MySql, effectively allowing me to pull data like ->username ->age.

Here is a mockup of what I want to achieve next.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/61550675/mockup.png

When a person clicks on an Avatar, I want the information block div to slide down (easy) with the mySql data from that person(Un-sure). So, it refreshes with the persons data that was clicked on.

What would be the best approach for this? I would love some ideas!

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "best approach". Do you mean how could you do this? Those two words confuse me. But I understand what you are asking.

Comment: what about using AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript to make an ajax call to the server on the element click, loading the user's information into the DIV and then sliding it open. You can do all of that with a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

Comment: Hopefully that is what this person should be asking.

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Be aware of "*what is the best approach*" questions - these are not constructive.
2. You do not need to use AJAX call - simply load the user information and output it to a hidden div (e.g. with a CSS class that has a `display: none;` rule, or simply by writing an inline CSS attribute `<div style="display: none;">CONTENT</div>`)
3. After a `mouseover` or `click` (that is Your choice, but `mouseover` is better I guess) just show the hidden div.
4. On `mouseout` (or another `click`) just hide that div again.
5. Use `slideDown()` + `slideUp()` or simply `show()` + `hide()` functions for this (or even `fadeIn()` + `fadeOut()`).

* Function calls are from `jQuery` framework...

Should be enough.

**EDIT:**
For a long term and (page load) speed up purposes, the use of AJAX, as **BotskoNet** adviced, would be a better solution. For this reason while retrieving the users and their avatars - `SELECT` only a concrete columns, that mean, if You need `avatar`, `name`, `surname`, `user_id`, do this:

```
SELECT `avatar`, `name`, `surname`, `user_id` FROM `users` ORDER BY `name`, `surname` ASC
```

**and do not do**

```
SELECT * FROM `users`
```

as this type of query loads unneccesary information thus require more resources (lineary depending on the users count).

The remaining information would then be retrieved after an AJAX request, like:

```
SELECT `short_bio`, `rating`, `country`, `website` FROM `uesers` WHERE `user_id` = <USER_ID FROM POST/GET>
```

That should be fine.

Comment: This is a fine solution as well but I'm assuming there's going to be a lot of different avatars on the page and it may make more sense to load the user information when needed instead of everything all at once on page load. It all depends on the reality.

Comment: @BotskoNet I assume they need to load the user info if they want to show user avatars with let's say their names or etc. Thus they are doing a SQL call and they retrieve the data. This is much simpler solution. Of course if they would have a page with thousands of users it would be wise using AJAX while retrieving the detail on demand...

Comment: Yeah it will be a very large library 'in time' so I would rather use the best long-term solution.

Comment: Then stick with AJAX. I edit my answer.